# Is difference between two sets of measurements significant?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Consider the following experimental setting: I have two machines $m_0$ and $m_1$ of which I would like to know which one performs better. For this I have set up an experiment to measure the time it takes a machine to perform a certain task. I have run the same experiment 100 times and have logged the time measurements, e.g. $t_0 = [0.1, 0.3, 0.2,...]$ for machine $m_0$ and $t_1 = [0.4, 0.1, 0.2]$ for machine $m_1$.

I learned in statistics about the $H_0$ and $H_1$ hypothesis and statistical significance, but somehow the hypotheses there were always given (as something the researcher assumed about the real world a priori) and I am actually not really able to apply what I learned there to my setting.

How can I check that $m_1$ is performing -in statistical terms- significantly better than $m_0$, for instance? What would I choose my hypotheses like? How would I perform the hypothesis test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good case for a nonparametric [Wilcoxon Rank-Sum Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) . Ill outline what you can do:

1. Your null hypothesis is that there is no difference between the expected performance time: $H_0: E[t_1]=E[t_2]$ the alternative is that machine 1 has a lower median performance time: $H_a:E[t_1]<E[t_2]$. Thus, under the null hypothesis, both sets of times came from the *same* distribution. This justifies the next step.
2. Rank the times in the combined dataset, then calculate the sum of the *ranks* associated with the machine 1 times. This is your rank sum statistic $W$.
3. Now, since you took 100 samples, the distribution of $W$ under the null hypothesis is likely to be close to normal. Therefore, we will use the large-sample approximation to the distribution of W: $W\;\;\dot{\sim}\;\;\mathcal{N}\left(\frac{n(m+n+1)}{2},\frac{mn(m+n+1)}{12}\right)$
4. Standardize W to get $W^*=\frac{W-n(m+n+1)/2}{\sqrt{mn(m+n+1)/12}}$
5. Check if $W^*$ is lower than  the lower-tailed z-test cutoff of $-z_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is your level of confidence (typically $0.05$ or $0.01$). If it is, then machine performs better than machine 2 at a statistical significance level of $\alpha$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on how to choose the hypotheses, this helps me very much. But I still got one question: Why did you choose here to use the Wilcoxon Rank-Sum Test (I guess it's the same as the Signed-Rank Test, right?)? Why not the t-test, for instance?

Comment: @navige that would be OK too, but I don't know what your data look like. If they are very non-normal, then the results would be suspect from a t-test. Also, the signed rank is a different test, and its applied to univariate data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!